# Partial evaluation in JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

My aim is to prepare some JSON data for passing to a third party script.  Some of the JSON data must be evaluated locally (it refers to local data or only has meaning locally), some is just a number or string data, and other data relate to functions or properties that will only have meaning in the context in which the third party script is running (the third party script will have additional libraries loaded).

Simple example:

```
getOptions = function () {

  return {
    num: 2 * 36e5,   // evaluate now (not essential though)
    str: "Hello World",  // just a string
    data: this.dataseries,   // evaluate now (load local data for use at destination)
    color: RemoteObj.getOptions().colors[2],   // only has meaning at destination... don't try to evaluate now
    fn: function () {                          // for use only at destination
           if (this.y > 0) {
              return this.y;
           }
        }
   };

}
```

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be better described as "Javascript code" than JSON.

Comment: you can wrap whatever properties you want in a closure and call it later? eg .. `getColor`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the properties you'll need and ignore the others, then send the correct object to its destination, like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'filter', {
    value: function(keys) {
        var res = {};

        for (i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) res[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]];
        }

        return res;
    }
});

var myObject = {
    key1: 1, // use now
    key2: 2, // use now
    key3: "some string", // use at destination
    key4: function(a) { // use now
        return a+1
    },
    key5: [1,2,3] // use at destination
}

var objectToSend = myObject.filter(['key3', 'key5']);
// now objectToSend contains only key3 and key5

console.log(objectToSend);
> Object {key3: "some string", key5: [1, 2, 3]}
```

**So in your case you will do:**

```
var myObject = getOptions(),
    objectToSend = myObject.filter(['color', 'fn']),
    objectToUseNow = myObject.filter(['num', 'str', 'data']);
```

Comment: OK hasOwnProperty looks interesting.  Thing is, I need to send *all* the data to the remote script... it's just that some of that data needs to be evaluated locally and then sent (e.g. this.dataseries refers to data stored locally, but needed at the destination), while other data just refers to properties or functions that need to be sent for evaluation at the destination.

Comment: Then you should process the data before sending it.. there's no need of filtering maybe, but that's your decision! There are too many possibilities to provide a "correct" answer for this.